# How to Pass Different Build Arguments to Projects of one Solution

Tags: msbuild, win-universal-app, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**Background**: We've got a single .NET solution which contains multiple projects, some of them are compiled against the .NET Framework, some against .NET Core (UWP). We use Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) to build our solution continuously.

**Challenge**: The UWP projects require different MSBuild arguments and platform settings. We created a build definition as per screenshot below: the solution is built first using the .NET arguments. Then, for every UWP project, we have an MSBuild step.

**Problem**: Every time we add, remove, or rename a UWP project we have to update the build definition. We would like to somehow select the UWP projects automatically, ideally using a Visual Studio Build Step and no custom scripting. Any ideas?

[image]

**Working alternative**: Originally, we split the solution into two (one solution per platform) and had two different Visual Studio Build events running against each solution. We prefer to work in one single solution though.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any easy way to achieve this without custom script.

You may trying creating a [MSBuild project file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx) and add your projects in it with separate arguments like following:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="Project1.csproj" Properties=Arguments1/>
    <MSBuild Projects="Project2.csproj" Properties=Arguments2/>
</Target>
</Project>
```

Then you just need to build the project file in your build definition. But this will require you to update the MSProject file when you have project added/changed.

Answer (score 0):

The Msbuild step supports wildcards, so you could set it to build `**/*.uwp.csproj` if your projects follow this naming pattern.